# Optimize image size while converting Bitmap into byte[] Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I am building a big app for android and I need to download&upload images to server. I did this converting with this codes:

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromGallery();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getByteCount());
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byte[] result = buffer.array();
```

But in this case image size is really big. How can I optimize it?

Comment: read carefully Bitmap class documentation

Comment: Which part do you mean?

Comment: its not divided into parts,  read it all http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: Thanks, Bitmap.compress fixed. Saving as JPEG decreased the size from 200kb to 30kb.

Comment: and you can control  the quality (0..100) as well thus reducing the size

Comment: thanks, but this process is extremely slow. for instance, it takes about 20 seconds to compress 200x200 image. Is there a way to increase it?

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream) ;
    byte[] result = stream.toByteArray();

Comment: strange,  really strange,  it should be like a thunder,  tried PNG?

Comment: That's it, png works as thunder :) Little bit greater size(38kb) then jpg(30kb) but much more better then raw image(200kb) and very fast thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to start read great tutorial by http://developer.android.com.
But before you have to start i am give you overview of bitmap loader class
```

-->you should match size of UI same as device
-->You can reduce size of image using [inSampleSize.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)
-->Read your bitmap dimenstion and type
-->Scale down image to device memory.